# Creating array with const int size parameter in a function throws error in Visual Studio C++: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants

```
void foo(const int size) {
    char array[size];
}
int main() { }
```

The above code throws compiler error in Visual Studio C++:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
```

Why is `size` not evaluated as constant even though it's declared as `const int`?
But the following code compiles successfully:

```
int main() {
    const int size{ 10 };
    char array[size];
}
```

Comment: If you want a term to google, then the array size has to be a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

Comment: `const int size` just means that `size` can't be modified inside `foo`, you can however pass any value you wish to it. For example `int x; std::cin >> x; foo(x);` would be totally legal.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles because size is truly constant.

```
int main() {
    const int size{ 10 };
    char array[size];
}
```

This however will not compile, because size is a constant variable, and not a compile time constant *(there's a subtle difference)*

```cpp
void foo(const int size) {
    char array[size];
}
```

The reason it won't work, is because I can call foo with differing arguments.

```cpp
foo(10);
foo(42);
foo(1);
```

The simplest work around is to use std::vector, which is what you are trying to do...

```cpp
void foo(const int size) {
    std::vector<char> array(size);
}
```

and now 'array' will work with the same intent as your original code.

Answer (score 2):

The size of an array needs to be a *compile time constant*, not just run-time `const`.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a statically typed language and `char array[1]` and `char array[2]` are different types so those types must be known at compile time.

E.g

```
void foo(const int size) {
    char array[size];
}
int main() {
    int x = std::rand() % 1000;
    foo( x ); // Error
}
```

In this case, compiler cannot know the type of `char array[size]` at compile-time because the size is decided at run-time, so it is an error.

So as @Frodyne stated in comments, size of static arrays must be [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)

Answer (score -3):

Since the constant variable size is initialized to '10', the value of the size cannot be modified. The size of the array is fixed and it cannot be changed.

int size = 10; // the value of the size can be changed.

Comment: The question is _"Why is size not evaluated as constant even though it's declared as const int?"_ how does this answer the question?